# [SWIFT]Presenting Modal View Controller with transparency in ios7

Tags: swift, ios7

Im trying to present a modal view controller in my app with the background transparent, it works for ios8, but for some reason in ios7 the background becomes gray and doesnt show transparency, Ive already set the alpha to the view in storyboard and below is the code Im using:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PopUpStoryboard", bundle: nil);
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopUpQuestionController") as PopUpQuestionController;
    vc.currentEvent = self.currentEvent
    vc.questionMode = "text"
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

the result in ios8:

[image]

and the result in ios 7:

[image]

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Are you trying to use blur?

Comment: no, im just trying to show the view controller like in the first image of ios 8